# plupload to s3 with metadata

Tags: amazon-s3, metadata, plupload

I'm using Plupload to upload images to Amazon S3 and I want to include metadata in the upload.

The configurations I send to plupload look like this:

```
$plupload_init = array(
                    'runtimes'            => 'html5,silverlight,flash,html4',
                    'browse_button'       => 'test_plupload-browse-button',
                    'container'           => 'testpluploadContainer',
                    'drop_element'        => 'test_drag-drop-area',
                    'file_data_name'      => 'file', 
                    'multiple_queues'     => false,
                    'max_file_size'       => '200mb',
                    'url'                 => 'http://myBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/',
                    'flash_swf_url'       => includes_url('js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf'),
                    'silverlight_xap_url' => includes_url('js/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap'),
                    'filters'             => array(array('title' => __('Allowed Files'), 'extensions' => '*')),
                    'multipart'           => true,
                    'multipart_params'    => array(
                          // 'key' => '${filename}', // add folder later
                          'Filename' => '${filename}', 
                          'acl' => 'public-read',
                          'Content-Type' => '',
                          'success_action_status' => '201',
                          'AWSAccessKeyId' => $accessKeyId,
                          'policy' => $policy,
                          'signature' => $signature,
                    ),
                    'headers' => array(
                        'x-amz-meta-author' => 'test'
                    ),
                  );
```

This does upload the file, but does not have the metadata attached. I tried adding it to the array as its own element and to the multipart params but nothing worked.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your policy must have a condition for your custom meta data.

`array('starts-with', 'x-amz-meta-author', '')`

Also I'm passing custom meta data as an additional multipart_params instead of a header. Not sure if it matters.